# Does Tesla's photoelectric "solar cell" really work?

Tags: electricity, photoelectric-effect, renewable-energy

Tesla patented a device for gathering energy from light, using the photoelectric effect. ([US 685,957 - Apparatus for the Utilization of Radiant Energy](http://www.google.com/patents/about?id=YitoAAAAEBAJ)):

[image: Telsa's photoelectric effect generator]

Basically just a sheet of "highly polished or amalgamated" metal (top) connected to a capacitor (the ⊔⊓ shapes) connected to the Earth.  (The other stuff on the right of the image is a load intermittently driven when the charge on the capacitor rises high enough.)

The patent says it would be able to collect energy from the sun.  Would this actually work?  Why or why not?  Does it need to be in a vacuum?  The patent seems to say that it works better in a vacuum but that it is not required.  Would the plate stay charged after electrons are thrown off, or would they be attracted and drift back to it and neutralize it?  How does the capacitor to earth make this better than a plate hanging in space?  It allows more charge to be stored for the same work function voltage of the metal?

The patent demonstrates that he doesn't understand the cause of the photoelectric effect ("sources of such radiant energy throw off with great velocity minute particles of matter which are strongly electrified, and therefore capable of charging an electrical conductor"), but he understands the results.

(Incidentally, I have tried building this with a piece of aluminum foil, electrolytic cap, and wire strong enough to stick a few inches into the ground.  I didn't see any voltage with a multimeter in bright sunlight.)

Comment: Extra image is not necessary, but you may want to add the description of the middle device. This image is very unclear.

Comment: Exegese of that "middle" device is rather easy, it is an electromagnet coupled to a cam wheel by a ratchet drive. This will make revolutions going on in the same direction although the armature of the solenoid makes a reciprocating movement. The thing more to the right side is a electrostatic switch I suppose. The idea is that those two leaflets hanging down like in a electrometer will contact after some potential is reached.

Comment: Electrolytic capacitors have low parasitic resistance (leakage current) and a high capacitance. These two features combine to prevent you from seeing any voltage (it will leak off too quickly). Follow the advice of Tesla and go with a high quality, high voltage capacitor. I suggest teflon. Make sure that your voltage measuring device doesn't short out the capacitor. To test this, charge the capacitor with a voltage source (be careful to not kill yourself, use maybe 12V), and see if you can detect the charge.

Comment: What Tesla was seeing was indeed the photoelectric effect. This is why he thinks that the beam consists of "positively charged particles". So it helps to use a metal with a low work function. This is a problem as the good metals are too reactive. But the shortest wavelength hitting earth is 100nm or around 12.4 eV and this is enough to knock electrons off of any metal.

Comment: Finally, it seems to me that you're restricted to the voltage of the electrons, i.e. about 12.4 - 4 = max photon - aluminum = 8 volts. I don't see how he got extremely high voltages. Maybe I misread it and he only got high charges (by waiting a long time).

Comment: @Carl: Those could be an answer

Comment: @Carl, endolith No, not at all. This is the Photoelectric effect, as detected by Hallwachs and explained by Einstein some years later. Ever heard about that?

Comment: @Georg: Yes.  Did you read my question?

Comment: @Georg: Yes. Did you read my comments?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The energy needed to remove an electron from a solid is called  the **[work function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_function)**. For most metals you would need UV photons (300 nm for Aluminium) that rarely reach the Earth's surface. Visible light can eject electrons from alkali metals, but the **quantum yield** (the probability of electron emission per incident photon) for pure metals is low (probably less than 1%). Materials like CsTe that are used in photocathodes have efficiency up to 40% (at certain wavelength) but they are expensive and difficult to handle in open air.
Silicon solar cells also utilize photoelectric effect and compared to metals they are efficient and inexpensive.

Comment: I would say that it is an issue of efficiency. In principle it could work, but there are more efficient ways.

Comment: Not exactly. For visible light the efficiency of most metals will be exactly zero because the photon energy is just not high enough.

Comment: So it is a issue of efficiency.

Comment: An efficiency of exactly zero is not really "an issue of efficiency".

Comment: If it was exactly zero, you would be right. But as you say in your post it isn't.

Comment: @JustJeff: good point. so if I want to charge the plate to 1 Volt, the energy of photons should be 1 eV higher than the work function of a metal, then electrons would have enough energy to leave charged plate.

Comment: A look into an old physics textbook shows which metal to choose and that this works.

Comment: But what happens to the electrons after they are ejected?  What prevents them from drifting back toward the positively charged metal?

Comment: @endolith: depending on the photon energy, ejected electron gets some kinetic energy - not more that 1 eV for visible light. As soon as the potential reaches one Volt, all emitted electrons will be attracted by the plate and this limits the maximal voltage you can obtain with such element. Below 1 V some electrons will have enough energy to escape the plate and produce a little current in the circuit.

Comment: @endolith: with conventional metals you would not see any photoelectric effect under sunlight. You would need UV lamp - not the one from solarium but the one used in hospitals for sterilization (emission at 254 nm).

Comment: @gigacyan: Even in air the electrons will be ejected and never drift back?

Comment: @endolith: I think that most of electrons will escape even in air - the velocity of electron having kinetic energy of 1 eV is 600 km/s ! Big enough to get far away from the plate before colliding with molecules of air.

Comment: On corona discharges, Wikipedia says *"A further feature of the structure of negative coronas is that as the electrons drift outwards, they encounter neutral molecules and, with electronegative molecules (such as oxygen and water vapor), combine to produce negative ions. These negative ions are then attracted to the positive uncurved electrode, completing the 'circuit'."*

Comment: @gigacyan 600 km/s, but it hits an atom and joins it in far less time than 1 second right?

Answer (score -4):

First of all, radiant energy was not light energy to Tesla. He was talking about an entirely different form of energy emitted by the stars. This is evidenced by the fact that this device will produce a charge on a capacitor even at night.

You need to use, as stated earlier, a high voltage capacitor that is of good quality. And it must not be electrolytic. If you use electrolytic then a full wave bridge rectifier using perhaps 1N34A diodes would be needed. But this is not what Tesla used. Read his patents. Also, it needs to be understood what he meant by "amalgamated". This term implies that perhaps he coated his plate with a mixture of metal powders and mercury. Or perhaps he just used a polished plate, probably copper. Experimentation needs to be done in this regard.
But don't be fooled by modern physics that state these things are not possible. Much is kept secret. Remember, at one time there were mathematical formulas "proving" that it was impossible to travel at or faster than the speed of sound. Well, they were proved wrong. Look at the SR 71 Blackbird that was developed just ten years after they broke the sound barrier.It could travel at speeds over mach3. Now they say the same about light speed. Who knows when this will be proved wrong.

Comment: Please provide some references 1 that Tesla didn't believe it was light. 2 that he claimed it worked during the night 3 why an electrolytic would need a rectifier but a nonelectrolytic wouldn't. (And where the rectifier would go) 4 that there were mathematical formulas proving that you could not travel faster than the speed of sound

Comment: @endolith And he never answered or asked on Physics SE again...